# Editing my attribute table or delete a feature with "Provider does not support deletion" message

Tags: qgis, editing, avenza

I used Avenza Maps to collect polygon and point data. I exported the polygons and points from Avenza as KML files, then opened them in QGIS.
They appear on QGIS; however, I am unable to edit or delete polygons or points and cannot make any changes to the Attributes Table.

I keep getting this message when trying to delete a feature:
`"Provider does not support deletion: Data provider does not support deleting features"`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 7):

QGIS doesn't support most of the editing tools for KML format, except *adding features* and *adding attributes*. Therefore, you need to convert your KML layer to another format (such as a geopackage or a shapefile).

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

You can't edit features saved in KML files with QIGS. Export/save to another file format (GeoPackage).

**Detailed answer**

Not every file format and not every data from every data provider are editable in QGIS. If loading data from a remote server (e.g. using a web Service like [WFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service)), it depends on the settings the data provider defined if you can edit the data. For file-based local data, it depends on the file format: So in QGIS, you can edit and delete features e.g. in shapefiles or GeoPackage, but not (or only in a limited way) for GPX or KML files.

In this case, export the data and save it in an editable format (GeoPackage recommended). For remote data, there might be restrictions you can't (and are not allowed) to overcome: In this case, your only possibility is to contact the data provider and ask if they can provide the data in a format that you can edit.